# RegEx to find if a string lies in a range of number strings

Tags: c#, regex, string, powerbuilder

Here I have a strange issue, I'm trying to replicate a behavior found in powerbuilder, to C#.

Here is the choose case statement in powerbuilder

```
CHOOSE CASE ls_char
   CASE "_" 
      ls_char = "-"
   CASE "0" to "9"
      MESSAGEBOX("DIGIT")
END CHOOSE
```

Now here comes the issue:
ls_char can be a string or a char but still powerbuilder finds if it's equivalent numeric value falls between "0" and "9".
We have even tried it by giving "0" TO "900" and giving ls_char = "300" and it pops the messagebox.

Any guidance regarding having some regex to achieve this or any other solution would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can try regex: `[0-9-]`

Comment: Nothing to do with regex (at least regex has nothing to do with powerbuilder CHOOSE statement).

Comment: ls_char suggests a relation to char, which is a single character data type. Are you certain that this function is intended to take a value in ls_char larger than a single character? If intended for a single character, this script would make much more sense. (Hint: "1ABC" will throw "DIGIT", which doesn't make sense.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PowerScript `CHOOSE` statement doesn't compare *"...equivalent numeric value..."*, it just compares objects as they are (in this case strings, without any further processing). "9" is greater than "0" as "999" is greater than "000" (you can try "11" is smaller than "2").

From [PowerScript reference manual](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/topic/com.sybase.infocenter.dc37781.1250/html/psref/CCJDAGDC.htm) documentation for `expressionlist` parameter in `CASE` you can see `TO` clause accepts just values, conversion is usually made from `testexpression` type to `expressionlist` type(s) and not vice-versa. It means that if you provide strings then it'll compare strings instead of numbers!

There is not an equivalent of `CHOOSE` in C# and `switch` statement can't be used like that (you can find it, for example, in VB.NET for [Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cy37t14y.aspx) statement). Workaround is to use `if` instead:

```
string text = ls_char.ToString();
if (text == "_")
    ls_char = "-";
else if (text >= "0" && text <= "9")
    MessageBox.Show("Digit");
```

To compare numbers what you have to do is to provide numbers in `CASE` blocks:

```
CHOOSE CASE long(ls_char)
   CASE 0 TO 5
      MESSAGEBOX("SMALLER")
   CASE 6 TO 9
      MESSAGEBOX("SMALL")
END CHOOSE
```

In this case ls_char (whatever is its type) is converted to a number and then compared to check if it's in requested range. Roughly in C# it's equivalent to this:

```
int number = Convert.ToInt32(ls_char);
if (number >= 0 && number <= 5)
    MessageBox.Show("Smaller");
else if (number >= 6 && number <= 9)
    MessageBox.Show("Small");
```

Comment: Did you tried that? Provided that ls_char is a char type, using it in numeric `choose case` gives a compile error `C0011: Incompatible types in expression: long, character`

Comment: @Seki thank you, wrote directly here and forget conversion. Fixed.